# Why is the Jobs button purposefully added in middle of question and tags?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently noticed the Jobs button on SO, which has been strategically placed in between Question and tags. I believe these 2 buttons to be the most commonly used and long time users are accustomed to the design and will this subconsciously move their mouse there and click it.

Is that the reason why it was placed there, then I feel like that is taking disadvantage of users. Or am I wrong?

Comment: So as you're going to click the tags and instead click "jobs" :/ I find this pretty uncomfortable.

Comment: @nicael : Exactly. I hope you are not being sarcastic.

Comment: No jokes, it's actually very inconvenient (+1).